# Open View Controller Scene Programmatically (Swift 4)

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift4

I want to create a basic iOS app that has two buttons. Tap the first button to show view controller 1, tap the second button to show view controller 2.

How Can I do this by swift code.

I connected the first button to the following code on the root view controller:

```
@IBAction func showViewOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // this is where I need help I think
}
```

I also have shell swift files created for each of the view controllers I wish to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
@IBAction func showViewOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifierName") as! yourClassname(e.g PhoneNoDropDownViewController)
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }


@IBAction func showViewTwoTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifierName") as! yourClassname(e.g PhoneNoDropDownViewController)
            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
```

Comment: I get this when trying to run: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.' And the debugger shows me this line: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: clear your segues from viewController...then try this.Or delete your viewController and take a new one then connect the button and try it..hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I guess the vc had some clutter in it... deleting/re-adding fixed it.  Thx.

Comment: welcome. you can accept this answer if you want :) . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1Identifier") as! ViewController1
self.present(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I get this when trying to run: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

And the debugger shows me this line: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {    Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! LoginViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

[image: **How to add Storyboard id (withIdentifier)**]

Comment: I get this when trying to run: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.' And the debugger shows me this line: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: can you give me a screen shot of your storyboard and full ViewController code?